# STM32F407 DISC board running with stm32CubeIDE debugger connection lost

Tags: stm32f4discovery

when i try to run my stm32f407 disc board with cubeIDE it shows connection lost.
i have tried

1.setting swd pins manually

2.updating drivers
but nothing is solving the issue.